# Adding timer and web links to a random image system?

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a random image system that keeps changing each time you load the page.

What I am trying to do its get it also to at the same time:

1. that the image changes randomly every 15 seconds

and

2. That you can click on each random image it has a web link attached to it.

--

I need it running in a standard html page so needs to use javascript

var timerid = setInterval(changeImage(), 1000);

Not sure how to set this within code:

random_img[2] = '';

Hope you can help as I can't work it out :-(

Thanks

Tim

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Displaying a Random Image</title>
<style type="text/css">
p {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#kirupaLogo {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px -2px #333;
}
body {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
h4 {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #999999;
    font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Displaying a Random Image</p>
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img id="randomImage" alt="The great wall of Merlin!" /> <br />
<br />

<script>

function getRandomImage() {
    var images = ['http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/4.jpg',
'http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/1.jpg', 'http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/2.jpg', 'http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/3.jpg', 'http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/4.jpg', '5http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/randon/.jpg', 'http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/6.jpg', 'http://www.tcdesignstamford.co.uk/random/7.jpg' ];
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
    
    return image;
}

function displayRandomImage() {
    var htmlImage = document.getElementById("randomImage");
    htmlImage.src = getRandomImage();
}
displayRandomImage();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ImagesSrc = [<image_url>,...]

function changeImage(){
  // ind is random Integer between 0-ImagesSrc.length
  let ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * ImagesSrc.length);
  document.getElementById('randomImage').src = ImagesSrc[ind];
}
```